# tableHeaderView displays with full height using auto layout and storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uistoryboard

**UPDATE**

I couldn't recreate the problem when starting a new project from scratch. The tableHeaderView's height always matched the height I had in the storyboard. However, if I copy my storyboard into a brand new project and set it as the main storyboard, the problem can be seen.

You can download my test project here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k5kc4syk563mm5y/AAAct3YbNp_S133rt7-iaftia?dl=0

---

In a storyboard, I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView`. I dragged and dropped a `UIVIew` (the purple view) on top of the table view, and Xcode automatically generated a `tableHeaderView` for me.

[image]

When I build and run, the `tableHeaderView` takes up the entire screen.

[image]

If I `NSLog` the tableHeaderView's frame in `viewDidAppear` on an iPhone 6, I get `{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}`.

There are tons of SO Q/A about resetting the `tableHeaderView` if you have multiline labels, where the recommendation is to use the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` API:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    UIView *headerView = self.tableHeaderView;

    [headerView setNeedsLayout];
    [headerView layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    NSLog(@"height: %@", @(height));

    headerView.frame = ({
        CGRect headerFrame = headerView.frame;
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        headerFrame;
    });

    self.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

}

I've tried this, and a) that's not even working for me, because `height` ends up being 0, and b) at this point I'm just trying to print out my dummy labels, which have a fixed height.

How do I configure my `tableHeaderView` in my storyboard so the height displays similarly when running on a device?

Comment: Does your table view have constraints set on it? If so, what constraints does it have?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem. When I set this up, the header is the same size as what I set it to in the storyboard.

Comment: in my testing, i can get it to display full screen with or without constraints on my uitableview.

Comment: same for me @rdelmar. i can't recreate it in a clean project. which makes me think i have a corrupt storyboard.

Comment: @rdelmar, I just recreated the problem by copying my storyboard into a new project. You can get the project here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k5kc4syk563mm5y/AAAct3YbNp_S133rt7-iaftia?dl=0. Are you able to take a look?

Comment: I will take a look now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75444/discussion-between-djibouti33-and-rdelmar).

Comment: do you want to add UIVIew to table header?

Comment: @ZaidPathan i Just posted an answer. No real solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Jaques answer I had to manually edit the tableHeaderView height property to be what I wanted. This must be a bug in Storyboard.

I searched for "tableHeaderView" in TextEdit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in my project. I used a text editor to changed the storyboard file directly. And, the problem was solved.

Comment: What did you have to change or edit to get it working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think the root of the problem was a corrupt storyboard. There are different ways to fix this (none of them ideal), like deleting and recreating the view controller, or even trashing the storyboard and starting over.

Comment: Having the same issue, with two tables in two storyboards. It must be something else

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. What about creating an IBOutlet of the UIView in the header and assign the height from there?

```
 @IBOutlet weak var layerView: UIView!
```

Then in View Did Load

```
layerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.width, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 200))
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(outletTableHeaderView)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful other users with similar issues.